# Repost an embed message by ID discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, discord, discord.py

I just want to get the content of an embed. I don't even know if that is even possible.
That was my try.

```
async def getEmbedContent(ctx):
    print("start")
    msg = await ctx.fetch_message(828964689648156702) # <-- embed ID
    print(msg.embeds)
    print("done")
```

The console is printing that:

```
start
[<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000001D2F83D2790>]
done
```

How do I get the hole content of the embed to repost it again into a channel?

Answer (score 3):

`msg.embeds` returns a list of all `Embeds` attached to the message, so you can just access their fields like you would get the fields from any other class. For example, to get the title:

```py
>>> print(msg.embeds[0].title)
embed_title_goes_here
```

To repost it, all you have to do is get the `discord.Embed` instance & send that. This is the same process as sending an `Embed` that you created yourself, because both cases are the exact same: sending a `discord.Embed`.

```py
await ctx.send(embed=msg.embeds[0])
```